# Two functions have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Tags: java

I have the four classes:

```
public class Person {
    protected String name;
    private List<Address> addressList;

    public void setAddressList(List<Address> addressList) {
        this.addressList = addressList;
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("The person's name is " + this.name);
    }
}
```

```
public class Student extends Person {
    private List<StudentAddress> addressList;

    public void setAddressList(List<StudentAddress> addressList) {
        this.addressList = addressList;
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("The student's name is " + this.name);
    }
}
```

```
public class Address {
// Yes it is empty
}
```

```
public class StudentAddress extends Address {
// It is empty as well, just wanted to show that it extends the Address class
}
```

When I compile the code, the compiler throws `java: name clash: setAddressList(java.util.List<StudentAddress>) in Student and setAddressList(java.util.List<Address>) in Person have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`

I know there is a lot of posts online that explains that the compiler will see both `setAddressList(List<Address> addressList)` and `setAddressList(List<StudentAddress> addressList)` as `setAddressList(List addressList)` (the "same erasure" part in the error message), but I couldn't find any answers related to the "yet neither overrides the other" part of the error message. Apparantly, I am trying to override the `setAddressList` in the `Student` class, but somehow the compiler thinks I am not overriding it. But overriding the `printName()` method seemed to work perfectly fine.

One thing I tried is that the if I change the `setAddressList` to become `setAddressList(List addressList)`, then the code can compile. But if I need to access the data in the list, I will need to explicitly cast the item from `Object` to `Address` or `StudentAddress`.

Ideally I would like to keep the type for the list so that I do not need to do the casting. Thanks.

Comment: If I do `Person p = new Student();`, and then `p.setAddressList(List.of(new Address()))`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Do you use Person as a instance in somewhere else?

Comment: Generics has some rules built in compilation to mitigate risk when the method is used in a non-generic way (legacy). 1. Compiler may have a bug, 2. Did you try adding an explicit @Override annotation?

Comment: "yet neither overrides the other" – did you try to add `@Override`? But if that doesn't help, you could make your person a `Person<A>` with `List<A>` and your student a `Student extends Person<StudentAddress>`. Note that your current student implementation has a second list of addresses (the parent class has a list and the child class has a list. The lists are not related in any way and are distinct, separate fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "yet neither overrides the other" part of the error message is required because if one method overrides the other, then the problem of having the same erasure goes away.

The problem of having the same erasure is that the two methods will have the same JVM signature, and the call would be ambiguous. However, if one overrides another, then there is no ambiguity. Which one to call only depends on the runtime type of the instance. Even if you are calling it with `super`, there is also no ambiguity, because the superclass is trivially known.

It is not type-safe for `setAddressList(List<StudentAddress>)` to override `setAddressList(List<Address>)`, so the [overriding rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) prohibit this. Think about what you could do if overriding were allowed.

You could do:

```
Person p = new Student();
List<Address> notStudentAddresses = List.of(new Address());
// the setAddressList in Person takes a List<Address>, so this is possible
p.setAddressList(notStudentAddress);
```

What would the code do? Suppose the methods *do* override each other. Then `setAddressList(notStudentAddress)` would call the implementation in `Student`. And that assigns `notStudentAddresses` to the `List<StudentAddress>` field in `Student`. But `notStudentAddresses` is not a `List<StudentAddress>`! We therefore have a problem.

That said, it is also not type-safe in this regard for `setAddressList(List<StudentAddress>)` to override `setAddressList(List)` either, but the overriding rules allow this anyway (by introducing the concept of [*subsignatures*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), which is a necessary condition for overriding). This is because it is more convenient to use old code written before Java had generics this way.

```
public class SomeVeryOldClass {
    // Suppose this is designed to take a List<String>, but there were no way to say that back then
    public void doThingsWithStrings(List strings) { ... }
}
```

```
public class NewClass extends SomeVeryOldClass {
    // I don't have to take a raw type List in my overridden method
    // whoever directly using the new class would be type-safe
    @Override
    public void doThingsWithStrings(List<String> strings) { ... }
}
```